# Gradient on MPart tab not working as expected

Tags: css, swt, eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm styling my E4 application using css. Now when I change my MPart tab color and gradient it will also color the backgroud of the tab.

My css looks like:

```
.MPartStack {
    swt-tab-renderer: url('bundleclass://org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.CTabRendering');
    swt-selected-tab-fill: #F0F0F0;
    swt-unselected-tabs-color: #F0F0F0;
    swt-outer-keyline-color: #A0A0A0;
    swt-tab-outline: #A0A0A0;
    padding: 0px 2px 2px;
    swt-shadow-visible: false;
    swt-mru-visible: false;
    color: black;
    swt-tab-height: 22px;
}

.MPartStack.active {
    swt-selected-tab-fill: #F0F0F0 #99B4D1 100%;
    swt-unselected-tabs-color: #F0F0F0;
    swt-outer-keyline-color: #A0A0A0;
    swt-tab-outline: #A0A0A0;
    swt-shadow-visible: false;
}

.MPartStack, .MPart {
    font-family: '#org-eclipse-ui-workbench-TAB_TEXT_FONT';
    swt-corner-radius: 6;
    swt-simple: true;
}
```

Now it looks like:
[image]

And the color in the red square need to be changed.
[image]

When I change the swt-selected-tab-fill to only use one color it works correctly. But when adding the gradient (swt-selected-tab-fill: #F0F0F0 #99B4D1 100%;) it will color the background of the tab. How can I place a gradient on the tab but without changing the backgroud color?

Comment: This seems to be deliberate behavior in the tab renderer. I think you would probably have to write a replacement renderer for the `swt-tab-renderer` to change it.

Comment: Are there some instruction on how to replace it? I don't have a lot of time to implement this behavior. My customer wants this ASAP in their application.

Comment: I don't know of anything.